# pages loading slow

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, onepage-checkout, performance

I'm currently facing a slow page load <s>with the checkout being the slowest of all with</s>:

- 28 requests
- 18.5 KB transferred (rest cached from disk or memory)
- Finish: 15.24s (loader disappears and the user can do something)
- DOMContentLoaded: 6.45s
- Load: 10.28s

Loading checkout/cart ends with:

- 29 requests
- 28.5 KB transferred (rest cached from disk or memory)
- Finish: 6.35s
- DOMContentLoaded: 1.9s
- Load: 3.79s

whilst an empty cart has this:

- 22 requests
- 8.2 KB transferred (rest cached from disk or memory)
- Finish: 2.78s
- DOMContentLoaded: 1.22s
- Load: 2.65s

I'm using redis for caching and all caches are active. Javascript is minified, merged and bundled as well as css and html. The server is pretty well situated with 8 CPUs, 16GB RAM and an SSD. Load etc. is never high enough to be even mentioned. Basically the server is sleeping...

There are just ~80 products and one store. We don't use the content part of Magento. Just product detail pages, checkout and customer area (as well as backend) is served by Magento. There is a CMS system "in front" of Magento which serves pages in less than a second total including media.

<s>I see that TTFB for the checkout document is already 5.66s.</s> With the Magento profiler enabled I can find that `magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body` causes most of that time. Although it is pretty unclear what exactly causes it. Here the profiler can not help much (me at least).

```
magento->routers_match                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            5.347600 5.347600 1  42,063,304 10,485,760
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    5.143997 5.143997 1  15,976,176 10,485,760
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       5.143980 5.143980 1  15,975,304 10,485,760
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->EVENT:checkout_allow_guest                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.000609 0.000609 1  82.464     0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->EVENT:checkout_allow_guest->OBSERVER:checkout_allow_guest                                                                                                                                                                            0.000592 0.000592 1  80.944     0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->LAYOUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.106220 0.035407 3  13,085,544 10,485,760
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->LAYOUT->layout_load                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.000666 0.000666 1  136.56     0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->LAYOUT->layout_generate_xml                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.005658 0.005658 1  174.632    0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->LAYOUT->layout_generate_blocks                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.099472 0.099472 1  12,755,648 10,485,760
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->LAYOUT->layout_generate_blocks->Magento\Framework\View\Layout::Magento\Framework\View\Layout::generateElements                                                                                                                       0.099462 0.099462 1  12,902,296 10,485,760
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->LAYOUT->layout_generate_blocks->Magento\Framework\View\Layout::Magento\Framework\View\Layout::generateElements->generate_elements                                                                                                    0.091426 0.091426 1  11,885,184 10,485,760
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->LAYOUT->layout_generate_blocks->Magento\Framework\View\Layout::Magento\Framework\View\Layout::generateElements->generate_elements->EVENT:core_layout_block_create_after                                                              0.000169 0.000003 51 -16.128    0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->LAYOUT->layout_generate_blocks->Magento\Framework\View\Layout::Magento\Framework\View\Layout::generateElements->generate_elements->Magento\Framework\View\Layout::Magento\Framework\View\Layout::generateElements                    0.000609 0.000609 1  52.76      0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->LAYOUT->layout_generate_blocks->Magento\Framework\View\Layout::Magento\Framework\View\Layout::generateElements->generate_elements->Magento\Framework\View\Layout::Magento\Framework\View\Layout::generateElements->generate_elements 0.000455 0.000455 1  26.952     0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->LAYOUT->EVENT:layout_generate_blocks_after                                                                                                                                                                                           0.000297 0.000297 1  16.32      0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->LAYOUT->EVENT:layout_generate_blocks_after->OBSERVER:persistent                                                                                                                                                                      0.000279 0.000279 1  14.776     0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->postdispatch                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.002972 0.002972 1  116.752    0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->postdispatch->EVENT:controller_action_postdispatch                                                                                                                                                                                   0.002913 0.002913 1  110.192    0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->postdispatch->EVENT:controller_action_postdispatch->OBSERVER:customer_visitor                                                                                                                                                        0.002900 0.002900 1  108.656    0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->postdispatch->EVENT:controller_action_postdispatch->OBSERVER:customer_visitor->EVENT:clean_cache_by_tags                                                                                                                             0.001175 0.001175 1  77.784     0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->postdispatch->EVENT:controller_action_postdispatch->OBSERVER:customer_visitor->EVENT:clean_cache_by_tags->OBSERVER:invalidate_varnish                                                                                                0.000516 0.000516 1  35.056     0         
magento->routers_match->CONTROLLER_ACTION:checkout_index_index->action_body->postdispatch->EVENT:controller_action_postdispatch->OBSERVER:customer_visitor->EVENT:clean_cache_by_tags->OBSERVER:invalidate_builtin                                                                                                0.000629 0.000629 1  41.08      0
```

I also enabled the database profiler but no query takes more than 1ms even though there are almost 120 calls. But that adds up to just 120ms then.

I generated an xdebug profile locally and can see that most of time is wasted in autoloading. But I'm not sure if that's "normal". I just wonder why file_exists is called so often. As I was under the impression everything is precompiled and cached.
I use `composer dump-autoload -o --apcu` after compiling di. And of course apc is up and running.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Yet I'm stuck here for now. I don't seem to be able to figure why TTFB is 5 secs already. And even if I solved that there is still 10 more seconds to explain and fix.
My main guess currently is that these are some xhr requests in the background blocking. Ie. I see estimate-shipping-methods only starts after an intensly long gap of about 7 seconds at 13 seconds and takes about 647ms.
Why does it wait so long to trigger that? Until that finishes the loader animation is displayed making the page seem to "hang".

[image: estimate-shipping-methods "delay"]

[image: checkout page load]

Any input is highly welcome! I hope for a page load of 2 - 4 secs max. as that's what I started with.

Edit:
I fixed the high TTFB. As said I'm using Redis for caching. Also for session caching but it leads to a lockup between two concurring sessions. Actually being the checkout request and the estimate-shipping-request leading to a 5 second timeout. I switched sessions back to normal file mode. Unfortunately this did not fix the long load time at all!
My current best guess is that something makes estimate-shipping-methods wait before being called resulting in a blocking of the page.
Additionally I tried to defer all JS with no change whatsoever.

Edit2:
As @peter-ocallaghan notes the problem with the checkout loading so slow (+10 secs) is actually just a chrome specific problem having the dev-console opened. Checkout/cart does not seem to be affected.

Comment: i dont know much more about it. i have facing this issue when i was calling third party api or plugin. This was occurred when I haven't received any response from it.

Comment: I'm currently trying to eliminate all that might interfere. I'm also calling a 3rd party api so I turned that off for a test. No change. So far I couldn't manage to rule out what makes the page load so slow.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that if you close the Chrome debugger the time will "magically" drop into (or at least significantly closer to) the 2-4 second load time. During investigations of live M2 sites, I couldn't understand how merchants would accept 15 second load times. I finaly realised that by using the chrome debugger as the timing mechanism, I was inadvertently slowing the request by an order of magnitude.

Comment: I was just testing this. Most pages take still at least ~4 seconds and cart up to 7 secs. But at least the checkout doesn't load in 15 seconds in all other browsers, more like 5 seconds. Seems this is something with chrome.

Comment: I managed to bring down the time some more by using memcached for session cache. As mentioned I used redis but that led to locking so I switched back to files but seems that locks too. So I switched to memcached and now the cart loads in ~2secs on the second load and 5-7sec on the first. It seems estimate-shipping-methods and totals-information are the blocker here. If I just reload the cart without any change, it's that 2 seconds. If I add a product or just change the amount and refresh the cart -> 5-7 secs.

Comment: Did you test without Xdebug because I think that Xdebug slow down Magento 2.

Comment: Yes of course. I use Xdebug just for local debugging. Live is "plain" and on preproduction (same server and setup as live) I use tideways.

Comment: Looking at more profiling it seems that estimate-shipping-methods and totals-information suffer from the session blocking issue. As they are not loaded when reloading the page without change to the cart the load time is acceptable fast with ~2 secs. When they need to be loaded the times rise to 5-7 secs with most of it being session_start. It also seems that the change to memcached session caching has improved the situation but doesn't solve it.

Comment: @steros Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report if readily available - 1 or more days uptime Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: Thanks wilson but I think it's a Magento problem.

Comment: @steros For basic analysis, additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.  Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  to allow suggestions based on your specific workload for a working day, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems my main problem is session concurrency happening for whatever reason.
I tried to use session caching with Redis as proposed in the documentation.

```
'session' =>
array (
  'save' => 'redis',
  'redis' =>
  array (
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '6379',
    'password' => '',
    'timeout' => '2.5',
    'persistent_identifier' => '',
    'database' => '2',
    'compression_threshold' => '2048',
    'compression_library' => 'gzip',
    'log_level' => '1',
    'max_concurrency' => '6',
    'break_after_frontend' => '5',
    'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
    'first_lifetime' => '600',
    'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
    'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
    'disable_locking' => '0',
    'min_lifetime' => '60',
    'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
  )
),
```

But as I have the session locking problem I think this comes into account:

> break_after_frontend
>
> Number of seconds to wait before trying to break
>   the lock for frontend (that is, storefront) session.

Meaning there is always a delay of max. 5 seconds.
When I switched to memcached session it got slightly better because the wait was lower.
It defaults to these settings:

```
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min => 1000
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max => 2000
memcached.sess_lock_retries => 5
```

These are the defaults from some older php-memcached version. The newest version proposes these defaults:

```
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min => 150
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max => 150
memcached.sess_lock_retries => 200
```

After reading these two:
https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/pull/350
https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/269

I tried with:

```
ini_set('memcached.sess_lock_wait_min', 150);
ini_set('memcached.sess_lock_wait_max', 150);
ini_set('memcached.sess_lock_retries', ini_get('max_execution_time') * 1000 / 150);
```

in Magento's index.php and this again speeds up the process.
I now get a load of the checkout in roughly 4 seconds. The cart is a bit slower with ~5 secs because of the loading of totals-information. (all first try no browser caching)

I suppose fixing the session locking problem would again speed up the loading times as looking at the profiles reveals there is still a wait for `session_start()` from 300 to 800 ms for several calls.

Comment: I am also stuck on this Sateros. I am using varnish with a workaround for https and Redis. Site is slow. Have been looking through newrelic and cannot find the conclusive answer. Is it the Redis issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Optimisations:**

- Minimize NGINX Redirects
- RateLimit Bots so they won't overload your server
- Redis Cache | https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/configure-redis-magento2/
- Minify css enabled
- Minify js enabled
- Minify html enabled
- Merge css enabled
- Merge js enabled
- Bundle js disabled
- Sign Static Files enabled
- css rel preload | https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-performance/blob/master/Magento_Theme/web/js/lib/cssrelpreload.js
- lazy image load | https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-performance/blob/master/Magento_Theme/web/js/lib/lazysizes.js
- Disable Useless logging | https://github.com/experius/magento2-module-logmanager
- Check if there are blocks which brake FPC
- Read the Magento DevDocs about performance | https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_perf-optimize.html
- Make sure you're running in Production Mode
- Use a cache warmer | https://gist.github.com/hn-support/bc7cc401e3603a848a4dec4b18f3a78d
- Debug if there are any events which can be disabled.
- Use Flat Catalog

**Profiler**

- Mirasvit Profiler | https://github.com/mirasvit/module-profiler
- MSP DevTools | https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_DevTools

Answer (score 0):

By using Solar or Memcache or Varnish , you can speed up your magento site.

Comment: I'm using Redis and memcached. I can't use Varnish as it does not support https and I don't want to use one of the workarounds.

Comment: @steros Please view my profile, Network profile for contact info and get in touch with me by Skype for assistance.